# In Site.com how do I create a page that displays data based on a URL parameter?

Tags: site.com, query

I have created a page at, say, www.mysite.com/mydirectory/dallas

And I want to display data in that page using the term "dallas" as part of a query to retrieve the right data. So I could, for instance, display information we have in our Salesforce record about Dallas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an alias redirect in conjunction with a data repeater.  Alias redirects are server side, so the end user navigating your site is never exposed to any sort of redirect.

Here is what would need to happen:

1. Set up an alias redirect (Site Configuration | URL Redirects) from /mydirectory/dallas to /mydirectory/dallas?id=recId.
   [image: Alias Redirect]

2a. In your data repeater specify that you are using an query string parameter of "id". 
[image: Data Repeater]

2b. (Spring '14): In Spring '14 [Page Data Connections](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=siteforce_data_page_connection.htm&language=en_US) are being introduced.  If you are on Spring '14 you can use them instead of the Data Repeater, if it fits your use page design. If you aren't on Spring '14, you can look at the [scheduled maintenance page](http://trust.salesforce.com/trust/maintenance/) to see when you will be.

Note: If you really need to use the String 'Dallas' in your query you can change the URL query string parameter to be that and the redirect and data repeater to use that.

I outlined some data and content strategies for Site.com in [this blog article](http://peterknolle.com/site-com-data-and-content-strategies/) that might might help if you are using page templates.

Comment: Peter, this looks great! Very helpful. I will give this a try and then come back and, assuming it all works, tag this as the answer. Thank you.

Comment: Just to be funny: Peter, referring to features introduced with Spring14 in the past tense ("were introduced") is totally incorrect, since the promised release has yet to be bestowed upon non-NA1 customers. :)

Comment: @DavidSchach - Good point! I updated the answer.  I needed Orders for something I was doing yesterday, and didn't have it in my Partner DE, so I created a new one and it gave me one on na8 which was Spring (w00t!).  If you need one immediately I guess you can try that.